# not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: .net, reference, compiler-errors

I have 2 WinForm Apps.

A completed, working WinFormApp1 has a reference to CompanyName.BusinessObjects.dll.

A fresh WinForm app with nothinhg in it has a reference to BusinessObjects.dll. when I type "Import CompanyName.BusinessObjects" intellisense recognized it and shows available methods when I reference contained objects.

However,. when I compile it, I get the error "not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." and it seems to no longer recognize the BusinessObjects project.

I swear this is a bug. This happened once before and I think I was able to clear it by bouncing VS2010, cleaning and recompiling all.

Now, nothing helps.

I'm desperate and ticked off because I think its a bug and I don't know how to resolve it.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/setupprerelease/thread/d2b627bf-b208-4763-823e-d5f34191b311) people talk of the same issue and resolution that previously worked but it isn;t working for me anymore.

Comment: You mention 'cleaning'. Did this include deleting the contents of the bin and obj folders?

Comment: Is your project on a mapped or network drive? There are new security requirements in place enforced by the .Net Framework 4 and VS 2010 that make accessing dll's from a network UNC difficult. Not impossible, but you will be better off if you use a path that is local to your computer, even if the mapped drive points to a local path.

Comment: I deleted the BO dll in the bin and obj folders of the BO project,  deleted the BO reference from the client WinForm app and the BO.dll in the client bin folder. I then reset the client app project reference to the BO project, selected "Clean Solution", then Rebuild All. Same problem. I am not using a network share-everything is on my PC

Answer (score 5):

Answer: Look to the Output window for clues.

```
BusinessObjects.dll" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
```

My client app was compiled against the CLIENT framework instead of the full blown one. The solution is to compile against the full, or preferably remove the Web dependency from BO, which is a pain now after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me and I found out that all it was that my `.designer` file had a `Namespace` included in the top. Deleting this fixed the projection issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in BusinessObjects that is declared as internal?

I think it might be a namespaces problem. Make sure everything is in the same Namespace then try again.

Comment: The problem seems to only be with my Telerik WinForms project. I get msg similar to the eror that this guy is getting with DevExpress: http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/69438/246555.aspx. I just upgrade my WinForm controls by first uninstalling. When I noticed that the uninstall left 150 MB on my drive, I decided to clean it up manually and then run a reg clean, as I wanted to load the new version to a different drive. I think I caused myself a mess. I hate uninstalls that leave gobs behind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your IDE i guess is Visual Studio as an Administrator?

Comment: Q: Have you tried running your IDE i guess is Visual Studio as an Administrator
A: Y         (15 character minimum in answering)